# The Forty Challah Bakers

Tags: sources-mekorot, segulah, separating-challah

[Tehilla R. Goldberg wrote in 2012](https://www.ijn.com/forty-women-baking-challah/):

> A common segulah that has gotten very popular in the last 15 or 20 years or so is that of 40 women baking challah for a specific person in need.

If there is a source for this? I would be very interested to hear how this started and if/which rabbonim recommend it.

Comment: similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7379/759

Comment: If one would make up a segulah, 43 people gematria חלה would be more appropriate, and the amount of eggs needed to be chayev

Answer (score 3):

In short: There is no source.

[Rav Shlomo Aviner](http://www.havabooks.co.il/sms.asp?cat=135):

> ש: יש סגולה ש-40 נשים יפרישו חלה כולן יחד ביום שישי, וזה יביא ישועה למציאת זיווג, רפואה או זרע של קיימא. האם בשעת צורך אפשר שחלקים יפרישו ביום חמישי? 
>   ת: זו המצאה חדשה שאין לה מקור, לכן אפשר גם באופן זה. ודאי שלהפרשת חלה יש ערך של קדושה – כמו כל מצווה – אך אין מקור ל-40 נשים יחד.‏

In translation:

> Q. There's a segulah that 40 women separate challah, all together, on Friday, which brings salvation for the finding of a mate, healing, or lasting offspring. Can, in case of need, some of them separate [the challah] on Thursday [instead]? A. This is a new invention that has no source, so that it is doable even that way. Certainly separation of challah has holy value, like any command, but there's no source for 40 women together.